# Monitoring Autocad Usage with Java

Tags: java, autocad

I'm trying to write a Java app for monitoring the autocad usage in my company... like a log with usage timing. Is it possible with java to check if autocad window (or any other service) is focused?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe thru something like :  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd", "/c", "taskmgr && doSomething"); , or ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "taskmgr && doSomething" ); . Of course there might be other better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for but you can get AutoCAD to write the contents of the text window to a log file. (LOGFILEMODE system variable, see also LOGFILEPATH and LOGFILENAME)
You would need to enable the setting and set the path and name on each machine.
Then you have the painful task of parsing the log files.